# Why does an ANN validation accuracy oscillate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

The following training curve is generated using the same *Tensorflow + Keras* script written in Python:

[image]

1. RED line uses five features.
2. GREEN line uses seven features.
3. BLUE line uses nine features.

Can anyone tell me the probable cause of the oscillation of the GREEN line so that I can troubleshoot my script?

**Source code:**

```
import os

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
#os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0" # Use both gpus for training.


import sys, random
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import numpy as np
from lxml import etree, objectify


# <editor-fold desc="GPU">
# resolve GPU related issues.
try:
    physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 
    for gpu_instance in physical_devices: 
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu_instance, True)
except Exception as e:
    pass
# END of try
# </editor-fold>


# <editor-fold desc="Lxml helper">
class LxmlHelper:
    @classmethod
    def objectify_xml(cls, input_path_dir):
        file_dom = etree.parse(input_path_dir)  # parse xml and convert it into DOM
        file_xml_bin = etree.tostring(file_dom, pretty_print=False, encoding="ascii")  # encode DOM into ASCII object
        file_xml_text = file_xml_bin.decode()  # convert binary ASCII object into ASCII text
        objectified_xml = objectify.fromstring(file_xml_text)  # convert text into a Doxygen object
        return objectified_xml
# </editor-fold>


# <editor-fold desc="def encode(letter)">
def encode(letter: str):
    if letter == 'H':
        return [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    elif letter == 'E':
        return [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
    elif letter == 'C':
        return [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    elif letter == '-':
        return [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
# END of function

def encode_string_1(pattern_str: str):
    # Iterate over the string
    one_hot_binary_str = []
    for ch in pattern_str:
        try:
            one_hot_binary_str = one_hot_binary_str + encode(ch)
        except Exception as e:
            print(pattern_str, one_hot_binary_str, ch)
    # END of for loop
    return one_hot_binary_str
# END of function

def encode_string_2(pattern_str: str):
    # Iterate over the string
    one_hot_binary_str = []
    for ch in pattern_str:
        temp_encoded_vect = [encode(ch)]
        one_hot_binary_str = one_hot_binary_str + temp_encoded_vect
    # END of for loop
    return one_hot_binary_str
# END of function
# </editor-fold>


# <editor-fold desc="def load_data()">
def load_data_k(fname: str, class_index: int, feature_start_index: int, **selection):
    """Loads data for training and validation

    :param fname: (``string``) - name of the file with the data
    :param selection: (``kwargs``) - see below
    :return: four tensorflow tensors: training input, training output, validation input and validation output

    :Keyword Arguments:
        * *top_n_lines* (``number``) --
          take top N lines of the input and disregard the rest
        * *random_n_lines* (``number``) --
          take random N lines of the input and disregard the rest
        * *validation_part* (``float``) --
          separate N_lines * given_fraction of the input lines from the training set and use
          them for validation. When the given_fraction = 1.0, then the same input set of
          N_lines is used both for training and validation (this is the default)
    """
    i = 0
    file = open(fname)
    if "top_n_lines" in selection:
        lines = [next(file) for _ in range(int(selection["top_n_lines"]))]
    elif "random_n_lines" in selection:
        tmp_lines = file.readlines()
        lines = random.sample(tmp_lines, int(selection["random_n_lines"]))
    else:
        lines = file.readlines()

    data_x, data_y, data_z = [], [], []
    for l in lines:
        row = l.strip().split()  # return a list of words from the line.
        x = [float(ix) for ix in row[feature_start_index:]]  # convert 3rd to 20th word into a vector of float numbers.
        y = encode(row[class_index])  # convert the 3rd word into binary.
        z = encode_string_1(row[class_index+1])
        data_x.append(x)  # append the vector into 'data_x'
        data_y.append(y)  # append the vector into 'data_y'
        data_z.append(z)  # append the vector into 'data_z'
    # END for l in lines

    num_rows = len(data_x)
    given_fraction = selection.get("validation_part", 1.0)
    if given_fraction > 0.9999:
        valid_x, valid_y, valid_z = data_x, data_y, data_z
    else:
        n = int(num_rows * given_fraction)
        data_x, data_y, data_z = data_x[n:], data_y[n:], data_z[n:]
        valid_x, valid_y, valid_z = data_x[:n], data_y[:n], data_z[:n]
    # END of if-else block

    tx = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_x, np.float32)
    ty = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_y, np.float32)
    tz = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_z, np.float32)
    vx = tf.convert_to_tensor(valid_x, np.float32)
    vy = tf.convert_to_tensor(valid_y, np.float32)
    vz = tf.convert_to_tensor(valid_z, np.float32)

    return tx, ty, tz, vx, vy, vz
# END of the function
# </editor-fold>


# <editor-fold desc="def create_model()">
def create_model(n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2, num_classes, num_features):
    # create the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(num_features,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden_1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden_2, activation='sigmoid'))
    ###model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_hidden_3, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    # instantiate the optimizer
    opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)

    # compile the model
    model.compile(
        optimizer=opt,
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics="categorical_accuracy"
    )

    # return model
    return model
# </editor-fold>


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # <editor-fold desc="(input/output parameters)">
    my_project_routine = LxmlHelper.objectify_xml("my_project_evaluate.xml")

    # input data
    INPUT_DATA_FILE = str(my_project_routine.input.input_data_file)
    INPUT_PATH = str(my_project_routine.input.input_path)
    CLASS_INDEX = int(my_project_routine.input.class_index)
    FEATURE_INDEX = int(my_project_routine.input.feature_index)

    # output data
    OUTPUT_PATH = str(my_project_routine.output.output_path)
    MODEL_FILE = str(my_project_routine.output.model_file)
    TRAINING_PROGRESS_FILE = str(my_project_routine.output.training_progress_file)

    # Learning parameters
    LEARNING_RATE = float(my_project_routine.training_params.learning_rate)
    EPOCH_SIZE = int(my_project_routine.training_params.epoch_size)
    BATCH_SIZE = int(my_project_routine.training_params.batch_size)
    INPUT_LINES_COUNT = int(my_project_routine.input.input_lines_count)
    VALIDATION_PART = float(my_project_routine.training_params.validation_part)
    SAVE_PERIOD = str(my_project_routine.output.save_period)

    # NN parameters
    HIDDEN_LAYER_1_NEURON_COUNT = int(my_project_routine.hidden_layers.one)
    HIDDEN_LAYER_2_NEURON_COUNT = int(my_project_routine.hidden_layers.two)
    ###HIDDEN_LAYER_3_NEURON_COUNT = int(my_project_routine.hidden_layers.three)
    CLASS_COUNT = int(my_project_routine.class_count)
    FEATURES_COUNT = int(my_project_routine.features_count)

    input_file_path_str = os.path.join(INPUT_PATH, INPUT_DATA_FILE)
    training_progress_file_path_str = os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, TRAINING_PROGRESS_FILE)
    model_file_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, MODEL_FILE)

    # command-line arg processing
    input_file_name_str = None
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        input_file_name_str = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        input_file_name_str = input_file_path_str
    # END of if-else
    # </editor-fold>

    # <editor-fold desc="(load data from file)">
    # load training data from the disk
    train_x, train_y, _, validate_x, validate_y, _ = \
        load_data_k(
            fname=input_file_name_str,
            class_index=CLASS_INDEX,
            feature_start_index=FEATURE_INDEX,
            random_n_lines=INPUT_LINES_COUNT,
            validation_part=VALIDATION_PART
        )

    print("training data size : ", len(train_x))
    print("validation data size : ", len(validate_x))
    # </editor-fold>

    ### STEPS_PER_EPOCH = len(train_x) // BATCH_SIZE
    ### VALIDATION_STEPS = len(validate_x) // BATCH_SIZE

    # <editor-fold desc="(model creation)">
    # load previously saved NN model
    model = None
    try:
        model = keras.models.load_model(model_file_path)
        print("Loading NN model from file.")
        model.summary()
    except Exception as ex:
        print("No NN model found for loading.")
    # END of try-except
    # </editor-fold>

    # <editor-fold desc="(model run)">
    # # if there is no model loaded, create a new model
    if model is None:
        csv_logger = keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(training_progress_file_path_str)

        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
            model_file_path,
            monitor='loss',
            verbose=1,
            save_best_only=True,
            mode='auto',
            save_freq='epoch'
        )

        callbacks_vector = [
            csv_logger,
            checkpoint
        ]

        # Set mirror strategy
        #strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/device:GPU:0","/device:GPU:1"])

        #with strategy.scope():
        print("New NN model created.")
        # create sequential NN model
        model = create_model(
            n_hidden_1=HIDDEN_LAYER_1_NEURON_COUNT,
            n_hidden_2=HIDDEN_LAYER_2_NEURON_COUNT,
            ##n_hidden_3=HIDDEN_LAYER_3_NEURON_COUNT,
            num_classes=CLASS_COUNT,
            num_features=FEATURES_COUNT
        )

        # Train the model with the new callback
        history = model.fit(
                train_x, train_y,
                validation_data=(validate_x, validate_y),
                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                epochs=EPOCH_SIZE,
                callbacks=[callbacks_vector],
                shuffle=True,
                verbose=2
            )

        print(history.history.keys())
        # END of ... with
    # END of ... if
    # </editor-fold>
```

**Plotting Script**

```
import os
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import random
from typing import List

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import sys
import datetime


class Quad:
    def __init__(self, x_vector, y_vector, color_char, label_str):
        self.__x_vector = x_vector
        self.__y_vector = y_vector
        self.__color_char = color_char
        self.__label_str = label_str

    def get_x_vector(self):
        return self.__x_vector

    def get_y_vector(self):
        return self.__y_vector

    def get_color_char(self):
        return self.__color_char

    def get_label_str(self):
        return self.__label_str


class HecaPlotClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x_label_str: str = None
        self.__y_label_str: str = None
        self.__title_str: str = None
        self.__trio_vector: List[Quad] = []
        self.__plotter = plt

    @property
    def x_label_str(self):
        return self.__x_label_str

    @x_label_str.setter
    def x_label_str(self, t):
        self.__x_label_str = t

    @property
    def y_label_str(self):
        return self.__y_label_str

    @y_label_str.setter
    def y_label_str(self, t):
        self.__y_label_str = t

    @property
    def title_str(self):
        return self.__title_str

    @title_str.setter
    def title_str(self, t):
        self.__title_str = t

    def add_y_axes(self, trio_obj: Quad):
        self.__trio_vector.append(trio_obj)

    def generate_plot(self):
        for obj in self.__trio_vector:
            x_vector = obj.get_x_vector()
            y_vector = obj.get_y_vector()
            label_str = obj.get_label_str()
            # print(label_str)
            # print(len(x_vector))
            # print(len(y_vector))
            self.__plotter.plot(
                x_vector,
                y_vector,
                color=obj.get_color_char(),
                label=label_str
            )
        # END of ... for loop

        # Naming the x-axis, y_1_vector-axis and the whole graph
        self.__plotter.xlabel(self.__x_label_str)
        self.__plotter.ylabel(self.__y_label_str)
        self.__plotter.title(self.__title_str)

        # Adding legend, which helps us recognize the curve according to it's color
        self.__plotter.legend()

        # To load the display window
        #self.__plotter.show()

    def save_png(self, output_directory_str):
        output_file_str = os.path.join(output_directory_str, self.__title_str + '.png')
        self.__plotter.savefig(output_file_str)

    def save_pdf(self, output_directory_str):
        output_file_str = os.path.join(output_directory_str, self.__title_str + '.pdf')
        self.__plotter.savefig(output_file_str)



class MainClass(object):
    __colors_vector = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'orange', 'lightgreen', 'crimson']
    __working_dir = r"."
    __file_names_vector = ["training_progress-32.txt", "training_progress-64.txt", "training_progress-128.txt"]
    __input_files_vector = []
    __output_directory = None
    __column_no_int = 0
    __split_percentage_at_tail_int = 100
    __is_pdf_output = False
    __is_png_output = False

    # <editor-fold desc="def load_data()">
    @classmethod
    def __load_data(cls, fname: str, percetage_int:int, column_no_int:int):
        np_array = np.loadtxt(
            fname,
            # usecols=range(1,11),
            dtype=np.float32, 
            skiprows=1,
            delimiter=","
        )
        size_vector = np_array.shape
        array_len_int = size_vector[0]
        rows_count_int = int(percetage_int * array_len_int / 100)
        np_array = np_array[-rows_count_int:]
        x = np_array[:, 0]
        y = np_array[:, column_no_int]
        return x, y
    # END of the function
    # </editor-fold>

    # <editor-fold desc="(__parse_args())">
    @classmethod
    def __parse_args(cls):
        # initialize argument parser
        my_parser = ArgumentParser()
        my_parser.add_argument("-c", help="column no.", type=int)
        my_parser.add_argument('-i', nargs='+', help='a list of input files', required=True)
        my_parser.add_argument("-o", help="output directory", type=str)
        my_parser.add_argument("-n", help="percentage of data to split from tail", type=float)
        my_parser.add_argument("--pdf", help="PDF output", action='store_true')
        my_parser.add_argument("--png", help="PNG output", action='store_true')

        # parse the argument
        args = my_parser.parse_args()

        cls.__input_files_vector = args.i
        cls.__output_directory = args.o
        cls.__split_percentage_at_tail_int = args.n
        cls.__column_no_int = args.c
        cls.__is_pdf_output = args.pdf
        cls.__is_png_output = args.png
    # </editor-fold>

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        cls.__parse_args()

        if cls.__input_files_vector is None:
            cls.__input_files_vector = cls.__file_names_vector

        if cls.__output_directory is None:
            cls.__output_directory = cls.__working_dir

        if cls.__split_percentage_at_tail_int is None:
            cls.__split_percentage_at_tail_int = 100

        if cls.__column_no_int is None:
            cls.__column_no_int = 1

        my_project_plot_obj = HecaPlotClass()
        i = 0
        for file_path_str in cls.__input_files_vector:
            print(file_path_str)
            x_vector, y_vector = cls.__load_data(os.path.join(cls.__working_dir, file_path_str), cls.__split_percentage_at_tail_int, cls.__column_no_int)
            my_project_plot_obj.x_label_str = "Epoch"
            my_project_plot_obj.y_label_str = "Accuracy"
            my_project_plot_obj.title_str = "training_plot-{date:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S}".format(date=datetime.datetime.now())
            my_project_plot_obj.x_axis_vector = x_vector

            if i  == 0:
                random_int = 0
            else:
                random_int = i % (len(cls.__colors_vector)-1)
            # END of ... if
            print("random_int : ", random_int)
            my_project_plot_obj.add_y_axes(Quad(x_vector, y_vector, cls.__colors_vector[random_int], file_path_str))
            i = i + 1
        # END of ... for loop
        my_project_plot_obj.generate_plot()
        my_project_plot_obj.save_png(cls.__output_directory)
        my_project_plot_obj.save_pdf(cls.__output_directory)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainClass.main()
```

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/264767) answer?

Comment: @K450, I am confused with the solutions given in the answer. Coz, none of them applies to my case. I have 1.4 million data points, my model is tuned by Keras-tuner before running the training, and more importantly, it worked well before with the same data points.

Comment: @K450, apparently, the problem started after I tuned the model's hyperparameters using Keras-tuner.

Comment: Honestly im way less experienced in this, but i guess try lowering the learning_rate and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Did lowering the learning rate help? I found oscillations were reduced in my model when I lowered the learning rate. Also have you tried 'Adam' optimizer usually it works much better "out of the box".

Comment: can you please post how you created the above plot? How many times did you run this experiment? It is very strange that the accuracy would decrease through training... Does the loss at least decrease?

Comment: @Galletti_Lance, plotting script added. I ran the experiment once. Yes, loss decreases.

Comment: I'm thinking about the data loader, sorry because I'm not familiar with Keras and Tf. However, you use the same code for 3 different sizes of the input and the training process performed weird for the middle, the data loader should be checked first, the function `load_data_k` may not load feature based on `FEATURES_COUNT`, can you check on that point first?

Comment: Also, this plot shows accuracy - could You please provide also CrossEntropy for the examples? It would be much easier to debug once we see both accuracy and cross entropy plots

Comment: @CuCaRot, that doesn't need to be checked at all. Coz, it depends on the input file. the column size is loaded from an XML file. If there is any mismatch, the TensorFlow generates an exception.

Comment: @w_sz, do u mean -- running training using cross-entropy function?

Comment: I meant recording it and the plotting. You are already training based on cross entropy due to the arguments in the`model.compile()` but I meant to provide a plot for it too. Its much easier to diagnose problems based on it. You can just add it to the `metrics` argument list

Comment: @w_sz, then, you have to wait several days for the output to be produced.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, sharp jumps and flat lines in the accuracy usually mean that a group of examples is classified as a given class at a same time. If your dataset contains, say, 50 examples with the same combination of 7 features then they would go into the same class at the same time. This is what probably causes sharp jumps - identical or similar examples clustered together.

So for example, if you have 50 men aged 64, and a decision boundary to classify them as more prone to an illness shifts from >65 to >63, then accuracy changes rapidly as all of them change classification at the same time.

Regarding the oscillation of the curve - due to the fact above, oscillation will be amplified by small changes in learning. Your network learns based on cross entropy, which means that it minimizes the difference between target and your predictions. This means that it operates on the difference between probability and target (say, `0.3` vs class `0`) instead of class and target like accuracy (so, `0` vs `0`) in the same example. Cross entropy is much more smooth as it is not affected by the issue outlined above.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason could be improper (non-random ~ ordered) distribution of data.

If you notice the accuracy beyond epoch 180, there is a orderly switching between the accuracy between ~0.43 (approx.) and ~0.33 (~approx.), and occasionally ~0.23 (approx.). The more important thing to notice is that the accuracy is decreasing (there's no improvement in validation accuracy) as we increase the epochs.

The accuracy can increase in such cases if you (1) reduce batch size, or (2) use a better optimizer like Adam. And check the learning rate.

These changes can help the shift and oscillation, as well.

Additionally, `Running average` of the accuracy can be plotted to avoid the oscillation. This is again a mitigation scheme rather than a correction scheme. But, what it does is removes the order (partition of the data) and mixes the nearby data.

Lastly, I would also reshuffle the data and normalize after each layer. See if that helps.